# Issue with scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** some precise lines and create table from collected data (url attached), but cannot get more than the entire body text. Thus, I got stuck.

To give some example:

I would like to arrive at the below table, scraping details from the body content.All the details are there, however any help on how to retrieve them in a form given below would be much appreciated.

[image]

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# providing url
url = 'https://www.polskawliczbach.pl/wies_Baniocha'

# creating request object
req = requests.get(url)

# creating soup object
data = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html')

# finding all li tags in ul and printing the text within it
data1 = data.find('body')
for li in data1.find_all("li"):
   print(li.text, end=" ")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to find the text quicker in body: Liczba mieszkańców, Kobiety, Mężczyźni.

Comment: Please try to give more detail information, like I want to scrape the part of this website, SO only support English. Try to give details in English rather then in other languages.

Comment: Thx for your answer. The page (link given in post) is typically about the PL census data.My questions is how to scrape No of citizens (Liczba miszkańców) split into Women (Kobiety) and Men (Mężczyźni). Hope it helps when it comes to language issue -:)

Comment: I have added also a screenshot directly from the webpage.

Comment: Yeah! It solves a little bit of language issue. But where exactly is that part in the website. Do you want to get that data from all `categories` or from specific one cuz the data of man and woman are in different categories. Please elaborate that screenshot with 1/2 upper part of data and same for lower. Because I didn't found that part while going roughly through website.

Comment: Do you want the data from just "LICZBA I PŁEĆ MIESZKAŃCÓW WSI BANIOCHA
Więcej" category only ? or you want form others also. And I am not preety sure if that is category or any other. Because I found as you told man and woman in other categories also. So, I suspect you want from other categories also.

Comment: Hello Kshitz. Many thanks for your reply. I have added one more png accordingly for better understanding where the text is. I meant exactly this text, because if I understand how it works, I will be able to go on with some other text-:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first find the `ul` and then try to find `li` inside `ul`. Scrape needed data, save scraped data in variable and make table using `pandas`. Now we have done all things if you want to save table then save it in `csv` file otherwise just print it.

Here's the code implementation of all above things:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://www.polskawliczbach.pl/wies_Baniocha')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

lis=soup.find_all("ul",class_="list-group row")[1].find_all("li")[1:-1]
dic={"name":[],"value":[]}
for li in lis:
    try:
        dic["name"].append(li.find(text=True,recursive=False).strip())
        dic["value"].append(li.find("span").text.replace(" ",""))
        print(li.find(text=True,recursive=False).strip(),li.find("span").text.replace(" ",""))
    except:
        pass

df=pd.DataFrame(dic)

print(df)
# If you want to save this as file then uncomment following line:
# df.to_csv("<FILENAME>.csv")
```

And additionally if you want to scrape all then "categories", I don't understand that language so,I don't know which is useful and which is not but anyway here's the code, you can just change this part of above code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

dic={"name":[],"value":[]}
lis=soup.find_all("ul",class_="list-group row")
for li in lis:
    a=li.find_all("li")[1:-1]
    for b in a:
        error=0
        try:
            print(b.find(text=True,recursive=False).strip(),"\t",b.find("span").text.replace(" ","").replace(",",""))
            dic["name"].append(b.find(text=True,recursive=False).strip())
            dic["value"].append(b.find("span").text.replace(" ","").replace(",",""))
        except Exception as e:
            pass

df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

Comment: Hello. Works as a charm. I think I get it now. This is exactly what I was searching for. You have made my day. GREAT THANKS!

Comment: Again, many thanks for your time & contribution! It is even more than I thought I could get.It's amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Find main tag by specific class and from it find all `li` tag

```
main_data=data.find("ul", class_="list-group").find_all("li")[1:-1]
names=[]
values=[]
main_values=[]
for i in main_data:
    values.append(i.find("span").get_text())    
    names.append(i.find(text=True,recursive=False))
main_values.append(values)
```

For table representation use `pandas` module

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=names,data=main_values)
df
```

Output:

```
Liczba mieszkańców (2011)   Kod pocztowy    Numer kierunkowy
 0  1 935                  05-532           (+48) 22
```

Comment: Many thanks for this one! It's almost exactly what I need.  Took some text location from inspector.It's class="list-group row", and li_class hdr col-md-12. However not sure how to apply it  directly in the code. I have added one more png to show where the text is exactly located in website.